# Bulk data load job isgetting aborted frequently

Tags: bulk-api

I have bulk data load job. I have job for record deletion, I use ETL tool. In tool i get error request time out and in salesforce UI i see job aborted and time taken as 1 minute 56 seconds. This job usually run when i try it second or third time.

I read docs but no luck and I am not sure how to troubleshoot. This deletion is for a custom object whose parent is account object.

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar and found I was hitting a query time out limit. Like yourself it wasnt obvious what the cause was (even with running the debug logs)  but with the help of salesforce support, who could see more info,  we narrowed it down to the query time out. Your timeout time is very similar to what I had. 
I would suggest looking at the query (try making it very limited to rule it out first) and/or asking salesforce support if there is more information that they can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like many objects related to the same parent (in a master-detail-relationship) being deleted in different batches.

Which ETL Tool are you using and how many objects are we talking about?

Also, can you set the batch size with your tool? Can you please try to set the batch size to `1`? This will allow us to see if the error is indeed related to different batches.